# modify map keys java - performance

Tags: java, collections

I have a requirement to modify keys of a linked hash map . This is my code .

```
Map<String, String> map = record.toMap();
Map<String,String> modifiedMap  = new HashMap<>();

map.forEach(
    (key,value) -> {
        if (key.endsWith("\"") && key.startsWith("\"")) {
            modifiedMap.put(key.toUpperCase().substring(1, key.length()-1), value);
        } else {
            modifiedMap.put(key.toUpperCase().trim(), value);
        }
    }
);
```

Is this way faster than the traditional for loop ? Also , any better way to do this ?

Comment: Faster?  Probably not.  If your map is so large that this O(n) operation takes a long time, you can try using parallelStream and dividing the work between cores.  How did those keys get into the map in the first place?  Maybe encapsulation and validation would be a better solution - keep them from being inserted in the first place.

Comment: you could get rid of the first `trim()` since you know that you string starts and ends with `"`

Comment: @Eugene, Edited my question . Thanks

Comment: @BMB I would personally avoid doing that in future. You've now made pkpnd's answer kind of confusing. Edit your questions to clarify, or to fix genuine mistakes which make the question incorrect, not to apply improvement suggested in the comments or answers.

Comment: @Michael . Thank you. Will not repeat this .

Comment: @duffymo this map is the result of a csv parser record and they keys are the headers .

Comment: Remove them when you parse.

Comment: @duffymo when using CSVParser, even with the setting withQuotes, the keys in the map that the csvrecord returns still have quotes. Any way to get rid of that ?

Comment: Did your solution work?  If yes, move on. Any improvement is marginal, a nano optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's as good as it gets. You can't make `O(N)` changes in less than `O(N)` time.

We can make stylistic improvements though. Note that `.trim()` is useless in the first case because `key` starts and ends with quotes, and we can remove some code duplication:

```
map.forEach((key, value) -> {
    key = key.toUpperCase();
    if (key.endsWith("\"") && key.startsWith("\"")) {
        modifiedMap.put(key.substring(1, key.length() - 1), value);
    } else {
        modifiedMap.put(key.trim(), value);
    }
});
```

Although I suspect you also want to `trim` after taking `substring`, in which case this becomes even simpler:

```
map.forEach((key, value) -> {
    if (key.endsWith("\"") && key.startsWith("\"")) {
        key = key.substring(1, key.length() - 1);
    }
    modifiedMap.put(key.trim().toUpperCase(), value);
});
```

Comment: @YCF_L Uppercase-then-trim is functionally equivalent to trim-then-uppercase but marginally faster as you don't have to iterate over spaces twice.